# Unable to extract attendance data in JSON postman

Tags: json, api, postman, zoho

I am trying to get data of attendance API from zoho people in postman application .. so for this i already get access token and now i am trying to access all data ..

I tried this link and paste in get

https://www.zoho.com/people/help/api/attendance-api.html

[image]

but this shows me an error .. here is only empid .. and i want all data in bulk so how i get this any idea kindy check image

image

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample URL that I use in Postman for accomplishing a similar if not the same task. (Be sure to substitute your auth token and data):

> [https://www.zoho.com/people/api/forms/P_AttendanceForm/getRecords?authtoken=YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN&searchParams={searchField:'AttendanceDay',searchOperator:'Between',searchText:'2020-7-8;2020-7-15'}](https://www.zoho.com/people/api/forms/P_AttendanceForm/getRecords?authtoken=YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN&searchParams=%7BsearchField:%27AttendanceDay%27,searchOperator:%27Between%27,searchText:%272020-7-8;2020-7-15%27%7D)

Answer (score -2):

strong text [DEMO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGZ5j.png)

should select output type in postman

Comment: what do you mean ? @Faaiz Ul Hassan

Comment: This should not be the answer, you're just formatting the response, but OP has asked for the error.